# A way to monitor android's TLS traffic

Tags: android, ssl, networking, openssl

Let's say I want to monitor the traffic sent by an android application because I don't trust it or I want to see if it's sending unwanted data to its servers. Is there any way to do it? Even if I have to run the .apk into an emulator or plug a cable onto my android, what I need is to be able to somehow see the traffic inside an application. Or at least a method to get the key between the client and server, and then monitor the traffic via wireshark and decrypt everything. Do you guys know a way?

I've read that java can't directly implement the RSA algorithm but its licensied VM executers can, so is there a way to get the key used into the openssl process running in the android? (i presume that's how it works)

Answer (score 0):

Sure. What you need is a MITM proxy such as BurpSuite. You install the certificate authority for the proxy tool and make it the HTTP proxy for your device. It will then generate new certificates on the fly for all the sites accessed by the device and capture the traffic. This can fail if the application takes extra steps such as certificate pinning but it will generally do the trick just fine.

Comment: But how to make the android send every traffic to the proxy? As I know, there's no way to proxy the entire android system, rigth?

Comment: There are several ways. One I often use is to connect the android device to a wifi network that also has the machine running burpsuite on it then in the network settings specify the burp machine as the proxy. You can also do the same by rooting the device and editing the hosts file. The emulator also has command line options for this. Finally you could also route all traffic through the burp host by making it the network gateway.

Comment: but as I know, the proxy defined in the wifi configurations is just for the browser, not for the apps